# NightmareJS without closing the browser

Tags: node.js, electron, read-eval-print-loop, nightmare

I'm used to PhantomJS and Watir, which both provide a REPL out of the box. The REPL lets me execute automation calls on a currently-running browser.

This is a fun way to make automation scripts because I can watch the effect of each step as I build an automation script.

In fact, I can even write a script that defines methods for opening a browser, performing a log-in, and other common tasks, and then call them as I please from within the generic Node or Ruby REPL.

**Can I execute NightmareJS calls without closing the browser (Electron)?**

Answer (score 3):

Without closing? Yes - don't call `.end()`.

If you're asking if you could disconnect the IPC - meaning the calling program ends but does not end the Nightmare instance - and then pick up the Nightmare instance again somewhere else, the answer is no.
[#393](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/393) (packaging Nightmare functions with an existing Electron application) and [#593](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/593) (covering v3 wants, including one Electron instance for many applications) are related, but I'm not convinced attaching IPC from new calling applications is a great idea.

If you provide more information about what your circumstances are and what you're trying to do, I'll edit this answer to try to help.

Having a REPL is a different question - I will add it to my list of things to look into.  It's a good idea.